# Where can I find the first version of linux operating system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Can someone tell me where I can find the initial code, Linus Torvalds shared with hackers. I was thinking it will be a great place to learn about operating systems.

Comment: http://www.kernel.org The very first kernels, starting with 0.01 are in http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/.

Comment: [http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/) has everything you need

Comment: His name is Linus not Linux, and I do not believe he was associated with any "hacker" groups. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds

Comment: [Here.](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/)

Comment: *Hacker* is not necessarily a negative term, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker

Comment: Wouldn't be complete without the introductory post: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.minix/msg/b813d52cbc5a044b

Comment: Linux is not an OS, its a Kernel. To see the first OS you need to go back and look at GNU's OS. The GNU OS originally used the Hurd kernel but to strengthen the Open Source movement RMS and the rest chose the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's discussed on KernelTrap. There's a good historical discussion, [complete with release notes and mailing list discussions](http://kerneltrap.org/node/14002).

The linked article comes complete with this gem, which is undoubtedly what Linus looked like after release:

[image: Linus Torvalds]
<sub>(source: [kerneltrap.org](http://kerneltrap.org/files/linus2.gif))</sub>

For the discussion, see [here](http://kerneltrap.org/node/14002). For the complete Linux 0.01 release, [download this](http://kerneltrap.org/files/linux-0.01.tar.gz) and verify it with [this signature](http://kerneltrap.org/files/linux-0.01.tar.gz.sign).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look at the history in a "nice" way, you could use [Dave Jones's Linux-History Git repository](http://Git.Kernel.Org/?p=linux/kernel/git/davej/history.git), which includes all versions (at least all the versions that still exist, sadly some of the 0.99 versions have been lost forever) from 0.01 to 2.4.0. There is another [history repository from Thomas Gleixner](http://Git.Kernel.Org/?p=linux/kernel/git/tglx/history.git), which covers 2.4.0 to 2.6.12 and of course everything *since* 2.6.12 is available in [Linus's Git repository](http://Git.Kernel.Org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git). Linus also has a [repository](http://Git.Kernel.Org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/old-2.6-bkcvs.git) which contains an import of the CVS export of the BitKeeper repository from 2.5.0 to 2.6.12.

You can use Git's graft feature to glue these repositories together to get a unified view of the entire history. There are also various scripts floating around that try to make these repositories even more accurate, like [this one](http://LWN.Net/Articles/285366/) for example.

Comment: +1: That's really cool (the guy who grafted all three, at least). I'm sure the commit history of Linux lends itself to some interesting data analysis...

Answer (score 0):

kernel.org is the repository for the Linux Kernel. Here is the "historic" section with really old code: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/

I'm not so sure old Linux code is the best way to learn about an OS. For starters, it's not an OS, it's just the kernel. Look into Minix, that would be more interesting, it was created from the ground up for educational purposes.

Comment: It's spelled "Minix". And you are right: Minix was *specifically* created so that the entire operating system could be taught in one semester in an introductory operating systems course. But make sure to get version 2, because this does no longer apply to the current version 3. Minix3 is much more complex than Minix2, as it is not designed for teaching but rather industrial real-world use.